# Update cell based on parent id ONLY if parent value is NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

Ive got help with making this query, but i need the query to only affect the cells that are NOT NULL

i had this question

> i have a table called 'person' that look like this:
>
> ```
> id  name    country father_id
> 52  bob     NULL    68 
> 68  joe     Maui    72
> 53  mia     NULL    68
> 51  robbie  NULL    68
> ```
>
> I would now like to run a query directly in the database to UPDATE all
>   person.id with the same country as their father_id
>
> so the person table will look like this:
>
> ```
> id  name    country father_id
> 52  bob     Maui    68 
> 68  joe     Maui    72
> 53  mia     Maui    68
> 51  robbie  Maui    68
> ```
>
> so my problem is how i do the update based on the person.id's
>   father_id's country

I got this solution below, but as mentioned above i need the update to only affect the cells with value and not the NULL cells...

```
update person p join
       person father
       on p.father_id = father.id
    set p.country = father.country;
```

Answer (score 0):

add `WHERE` clause

```
UPDATE person AS p 
       INNER JOIN person AS father
          ON p.father_id = father.id
  SET p.country = father.country
WHERE p.country IS NULL 
      AND father.country IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE person AS child
INNER JOIN person AS father ON child.father_id=father.id
SET child.country=father.country
WHERE child.country IS NULL;
```